# Automatic typer errors

Tags: java, eclipse, keypress, notepad

I am making  Java program that types a predefined message for you. I keep getting error messages for `getRuntime` and `exec`. I have tried to search Google but have found nothing. I have tried changing settings in my project and adding "throws", but nothing seems to work. I am very new to java so please be nice.

Here is my current code:

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class main {

Runtime getRuntime() exec("notepad.exe");

 Thread.sleep(2000);
 Robot r=new Robot();
 r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
 Thread.sleep(500);
 r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
 Thread.sleep(500);
 r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I);
 Thread.sleep(500);
 r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
 Thread.sleep(750);
 r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
 Thread.sleep(500);
 r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I);
 Thread.sleep(500);
 r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
 Thread.sleep(750);
 r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
 Thread.sleep(650);
 r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F);
 Thread.sleep(500);
 r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_U);
 Thread.sleep(500);
 r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N); 
}}
```

Comment: Post your errors with all the details.

Comment: @PM77-1 It won't compile. See the answer by Vivek Vermani.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe");`

Comment: I tried but it has an error on `getRuntime()` and the period. They say syntax error on token.